# How to reference rectangle/geometry objects in flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, geometry

I'm doing an geometry object tranformations for a project. I need to have same rectangle across 4 parts in a screen. So when i change one rectangle others will be transformed like scaling or something.

So i was able to do this with image, just giving "source" attribute. How to do with geometry objects?

```
    <s:Group id="rectangle" left="10" top="10">
        <s:Rect height="100" width="100">                              
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" weight="1"/>
            </s:stroke>
            <s:fill>
                <s:RadialGradient>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x11111" ratio="0" alpha=".5"/>
                </s:RadialGradient>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>

<mx:Image scaleContent="true" left="400" top="5" 
                  source="{rect}"  autoLoad="true"/>
```

Here i'm having a problem referencing above rectangle.

```
<mx:Image scaleContent="true" left="400" top="5" 
                  source="{rect}"  autoLoad="true"/>
```

Comment: <mx:Image scaleContent="true" left="400" top="5" 
      source="{rect}"  autoLoad="true"/>

This is where i'm having problem, i don't know stackoverflow din't post this in original post above.

Comment: You didn't format your extra images as code; so it is seem as HTML which the browser effectively ignores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the rectangle an ID:

```
    <s:Rect height="100" width="100" id="myRect" />
```

Then you should be able to access it via ActionScript.  The [Rect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Rect.html#propertySummary) has properties scaleX, scaleY, and scaleZ; but I'm not sure if that is what you want.  You could also just change the height and width to make something bigger / smaller.

Comment: yes thanks, now i get it. After working with images a lot, i could not figure out how to take one rectangle source and duplicate it other places.